# Uisng test-json on an array of json files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to validate all the json files in a folder using the Test-Json Cmdlet in Powershell 6:

```
[array]$myFiles=Get-ChildItem *.json -Recurse| select -expand fullname

foreach ($filePath in $myFiles)
{

try {
 $isValid = Get-Content $filePath -Raw | Test-Json
 $working = $true
 } catch {
 $working = $false
 }

if ($working) {
Write-Host "Is working for $filePath"
}
else {
Write-Host "Not working for $filePath"

}
}
```

If the json file is incorrect, the cmdlet Test-json displays an error referencing the .ps1 file not the .json file, hence the use of "Is working for" or "Not working for" along with $filePath.

However, regardless of whether the json files are correct or not it says "Is working for" for all the json files.
So I need either "Is working for"/"Not working for" to work correctly or even better if I could get Test-Json to display the erroneous json file rather than the .ps1 file.

Any help please?

Comment: The catch block never executes with default Error Action preference settings :) Why not just use `$working = ... |Test-Json` directly?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in using `Test-Json`.

Based on your code-snippet it seems that, You are assuming that it will throw error if JSON is not in correct format which is not the case.The error generated by `Test-Json` is printed on console but no exception is thrown.

In your case `Test-Json` cmdlet will just return `True` or `False` value and error message will be printed on console.

Following is the corrected version of your code:

```
[array]$myFiles=Get-ChildItem *.json -Recurse| select -expand fullname

foreach ($filePath in $myFiles)
{
    $isValid = Get-Content $filePath -Raw | Test-Json -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($isValid) 
    {
        Write-Host "Is working for $filePath"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "Not working for $filePath"
    }
}
```

Visit here for more information on [`Test-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/test-json?view=powershell-6), here on [`-ErrorAction`, `$ErrorActionPreference` and `-ErrorVariable`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/) and here on [ActionPreference Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.actionpreference?view=pscore-6.2.0).

Comment: Thanks for updating.